# The decoding of JSON not happening for bulk of contact numbers

Tags: php, android, json

I have converted 400 contact numbers to JSON object and I send it to the PHP. I am able to receive the JSON file which I confirmed by below.

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $jsonString;
```

android code  for conversion of contact numbers to JSON:

```
 JSONimdb = new JSONObject();
 for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {

     try {
         JSONimdb.put("genere"+String.valueOf(i+1), aa.get(i));
         Log.e("Shiva","phone-->"+aa.get(i));

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 EverythingJSON = new JSONObject();
 try {
     EverythingJSON.put("imdblist", JSONimdb);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I send this JSON by using Volley

```
   @Override
   protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        params.put("arr", EverythingJSON.toString());
        return params;
        //returning parameters
   }
```

Once i receive the JSON i am decoding it and parse it by using foreach.

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonString,true);
$imdb=array();

foreach ($obj['imdblist'] as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "came inside";
    //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
    $imdb[$key] = $value;

}
```

But the loop didnt executed. what is the problem here? This loop worked when i manually provide the values like below

```
   $jsonString = '{"imdblist":{"genere1":"+1 (000) 0000","genere2":"+1 (000) 000-0000"}}';
```

What is wrong here? is this is due to the number of contacts is more? or any syntax error? Please help.

Comment: You should post the data that is causing the problem, not the data that works.

Comment: @jeroen - There is an empty result after parsing decoded JSON thats why there is no data to post. Anyway i give the output of file_get_contents for first 3 values %7B%22imdblist%22%3A%7B%22genere1%22%3A%22%2B1+%28203%29+300-4029%22%2C%22genere2%22%3A%22%2B1+%28203%29+548-1201%22%2C%22